# Getting the height of a div after setting it to auto in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm writing some JavaScript that changes the size of some content.  To do this I need to know the size of a div within my content.  If I have the following html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
   ... other stuff ...
   <div id="inner" style="height:400px">Some text in here</div>
   ... other stuff ...
</div>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
$('#inner').height('auto');
var height = $("#wrapper").height();
```

In FireFox and Chrome the height variable increases as the inner div expands to fit all the text.  In IE this stays the same.  I guess it doesn't redraw the div straight away.  Anybody know how to get the new correct height in IE?

Cheers

Comment: Are you running quirks or standards mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It the problem is that the element doesn't redraw right away, then you need to measure the height asynchronously - set a 0-millisecond timeout to measure it and continue execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
$(function() {
  $('#inner').height('auto');
  var height = $("#wrapper").height();
});
```

Wrapping it in `$(function() { });` makes it wait for the DOM to render before running the script. It's probably a good idea to put anything that needs access to the DOM immediately after render inside that function.